# Display Artisian command output from DatabaseSeeder

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm calling a custom Artisan command which normally displays output when run.  However, when called from `DatabaseSeeder`, the interface isn't shared by default, thus no output is displayed.  Is there a way to pass the console output interface from `DatabaseSeeder` to `Artisan:call`?

If examples are more your thing:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {
  public function run() {
    Eloquent::unguard();
    $this->call('ApplicationsSeeder');
    foreach(Config::get('app.steam_appids') as $appid) {
      Artisan::call('schema:update', array('appid' => $appid)); // No output :(
    }
  ...
```

`Artisan::call` can take a third argument, but it must implement `Symphony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface` and I'm not sure if I can pass that from a Seeder object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correcting this as this is still the top result in Google for many related searches.

As of Laravel 5.4, `Artisan::call()` now accepts a 3rd parameter containing the output instance as it did previously.

Source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16763#issuecomment-268837505

Answer (score 4):

If you wish the output to be written to the console/terminal while the output is actually being produced, you can use the seeders own `OutputInterface` by calling:

```
$this->command->getOutput();
```

This can be quite useful if you got a long-running command that you wish to use in the migration (instead of having the console locked while the command runs, it might be nice to display a `ProgressBar` or similar).

Example:

```
Artisan::call('command:longrunningcommand', array(), $this->command->getOutput());
```

This will make the command use the same buffer as the seeder for output.

Answer (score 2):

Yes we can use third argument for output. BufferedOutput is what you need. It extends Output class which implements the OutputInterface. so you can use this BufferedOutput class instance.

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()

    {
        Eloquent::unguard();
        $output = new BufferedOutput; // instance 
        $this->call('ApplicationsSeeder');

        foreach(Config::get('app.steam_appids') as $appid) {
            Artisan::call('schema:update', array('appid' => $appid), $output);
            $output->fetch(); // returns content
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Laravel 5; it appears the $output argument for `Artisan::call()` got removed. Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: Yay, solved it. `Artisan::output()` returns the output of the last ran artisan command. So after doing your `Artisan::call(...)`, you can do `$this->command->info(Artisan::output());` to show the output.